# Map Control won't show up UWP XAML

Tags: dictionary, uwp, bing-maps, windows-10-universal, uwp-maps

I'm trying to run a simple UWP application on my PC to test the Map Control, using the guidelines in:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-maps#get-and-set-a-maps-authentication-key

I have obtained a map key from Bing Maps Dev Center and assigned it to the map control.

However, in the designer the control is shown up with a "This element is enabled only when the application is running" message.

[image]

When I run the application, nothing is displayed on the application screen.

[image]

To check if the map is loaded, I added a handler for the Loaded event of the map to display a message on the output pane, and the message was displayed fine.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    MapMain.Loaded += MapMain_Loaded;
}

private void MapMain_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Map is loaded!");
}
```

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestMap"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
    x:Class="TestMap.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Maps:MapControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="404,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                         x:Name="MapMain"
                         MapServiceToken="<My Map Key Is Here!>"
                         ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
                         TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl" CacheMode="BitmapCache" CanDrag="True"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Any thoughts on what could be the issue and how it can be fixed? Thanks

---

<<< UPDATE (Jan 25 2017) >>>

I changed width and height attributes of the map as per answers by @Sunteen and @Aditya. However, I only see a blank map frame, as shown in the below picture. I only see the map background.

[image]

---

<<< UPDATE (Jan 27 2017) >>>

As per Aditya's suggestion, I added my XAML code below to including the changes I made:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestMap"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
    x:Class="TestMap.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Maps:MapControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                         x:Name="MapMain"
                         MapServiceToken="<<<My Map Key>>>"
                         Height="400"
                         Width="400"
                         ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
                         TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl" Background="#FF3BCFCF" ZoomLevel="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit: (30 Jan 17)

Okay I should have seen this one coming, The issue not really about the `layout` just that the UI code was written such that it took all the focus to the UI layout and I thought that was causing the map to not show.

**The reason:** The map is not showing is because of the `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` property you're setting. Remove that and you should be able to see your map in a charming way. Now that you can see your map let's understand why is the `CacheMode="BitmapCache"`causing the issue,

**Why the `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` is causing the issue:**

Caching is currently disabled. The map tiles are dynamically generated. If caching was enabled and a change happened to the data it's possible that you would end up with two tiles with data that doesn't line up.

**The Work around:**

You should only load the map once in your application and reuse it across pages if needed to avoid the memory leak caused by the bing map.

To do so, you have to load the map on the main page, create a static variable to access the map, and then when your sub-page loads re-position & resize the map as needed.

**Your final UI code for the MapControl:**

```
<Maps:MapControl
      x:Name="MapMain"
      ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
      TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl" 
      CacheMode="BitmapCache" 
      CanDrag="True"/>
```

---

### Good Practices:

In @Sunteen's answer it would not be advised to use hard coded `height` and `Width` and using `400px` of `Margin` would just throw your layout out of screen on smaller screen sizes. It would be advised to keep your map element adaptive to multiple screen sizes as it's a `UWP` app, so avoid using `Margin` or hard coding the `Height` and the `Width`.

**What should be done:**

Another way of getting your map to show using adaptive layout would be to use `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` to set the adaptive height and width and set the `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` this ways your map control will be bound to a area and would adapt itself to change in screensizes with the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions`. So your code would look something like below:

```
<Gird>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Maps:MapControl
        x:Name="MapMain"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        CanDrag="True"
        TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
        ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl" />
</Grid>
```

To reposition the map based on how big you want the map and how your layout is, you can,

1. Add more Row/Column Definitions or even remove a few if not needed.
2. Resize the area covered by the Row/Column definitions by changing the Height/Width respectively, when doing so please make sure you do so in the factors of "*" for eg: `<RowDefinition Height="5*"/>`. This ways you would work more on screen size ratios than screen size pixel (this approach is more adaptive).

For more information on adaptive layout refer [My Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38848600/3766231). The question is for a windows phone 8 but the same rules would apply.

Comment: Thanks Aditya. Could you please my comment after Sunteen's answer? I only see the frame and the map is blank.

Comment: I also updated my question to include what I got by those changes. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @afshin can you please share what system you're using eg: OS version and visual studio version

Comment: Sure. OS: Windows 10 Pro, Ver: 10.0.14393 Build 14393 on Intel i5-2540 quad. VS: MVS Community 2015 Ver:14.0.2543.01 Update3. Microsoft .NET Framework Ver: 4.6.01586. Please let me if further information is required. Thanks

Comment: Great! In theory this is completely great for the app to run. Just one last thing, what actually happens when you do the changes we proposed and run the app. What's the view that you get. Also please add the updated code that you're using which implements the changes we've proposed

Comment: The picture you've added is of the designer when the app is not running. I just wanna know is it a blank white screen or is it a background you've set or is it the application theme colour when the app is running.

Comment: Aditya, I only changed Height, Width, and BackgroundColor. No major changes when I ran the application, except the map frame got visible with some default control buttons on it. But the actual map was not displayed. I have updated my post to include the updated code.Those are the only changes I made.

Comment: Great! I'll look into it. I am out of town. I'll look into it as soon as I get my hands on machine

Comment: Thank you Aditya. Looking forward to having some hints from you.

Comment: @Afshin I have updated my answer in a completely different way in order to address the actual issue in the top followed by the Good Practices, so that anyone else facing the same issue doesn't need to scroll much to actually know what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya for taking the time and putting your answer in a nice format. Your tips were so helpful. Just to clarify the last point, I had removed the CacheMode in my last update as indicated in my code above. However, when I ran the application today it worked fine and I had the same codes as your suggestions. I accepted your answer as the final answer, as it helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: @Afshin The funny thing is I wrote your initial code, the map wasn't showing then when I write your edited code in my machine, the map doesn't show as well all I could see was the background. Then I cleaned the solution, rebuild it and then from the file explorer deleted the Bin and Obj folders and then rebuilt the solution, the code worked. So maybe the issue was the same with your machine. It's a theory but that's my best guess as that's what happened with my machine using the exact copy paste of the initial code and then the edit. I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The solution for resolving the issue is easy. Set `Height` and `Width` properties for the map control then it will show.

```
 <Maps:MapControl
     x:Name="MapMain"
     Width="400"
     Height="400"
     Margin="404,86,0,0"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     VerticalAlignment="Top"
     CacheMode="BitmapCache"
     CanDrag="True"
     TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
     ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl" />
```

Or set the `Alignment` properties for the map control to [`Stretch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.horizontalalignment.aspx), the map will show.

```
<Maps:MapControl
    x:Name="MapMain"        
    Margin="404,86,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    CacheMode="BitmapCache"
    CanDrag="True"
    TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
    ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl" />
```

The reason for this may be that the map control doesn't set default `Width` and `Height`, we may need to set the control with properties such as `Width`, `Height`, `MinWidth`,`MinHeight` and so on. If we don't set these properties, we may need to stretch the map to let it show, or do not set anything to let it fit the parent container.

More details about map control please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl). More details about layout with XAML please reference [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml).

Comment: Thanks Sunteen. I followed what you suggested, now I can see the map frame. But, it is blank. All I can see is the map frame, colored with the background color, and at top of that frame "This element is enabled only when the application is running" message. When I run the application, I only see the frame and not the map. I checked out my map's key again, it it seems to be fine. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: I also updated my question to include what I got by those changes. Please have a look. Thanks.