# NavigationView can not to respond to interaction

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

When I add a custom title bar, it does not respond to user actions.

But remove `TextBlock`, It is OK.

I have added these code in `app.xaml.cs` `OnLaunched()`:

```csharp
//draw into the title bar
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

//remove the solid-colored backgrounds behind the caption controls and system back button
ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Black;
```

Xaml:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <NavigationView x:Name="NavView" AlwaysShowHeader="False" SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged" DisplayModeChanged="NavView_DisplayModeChanged">

        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Home" Tag="home">
                <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE10F;"/>
                </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
            </NavigationViewItem>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
            <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="ASB" QueryIcon="Find"/>
        </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>

        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="24">
            <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Frame.ContentTransitions>
        </Frame>
    </NavigationView>
    <TextBlock x:Name="AppTitle" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Text="Test"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the issue is quite trivial.

### Issue:

The reason why you can't interact with your `NavigationView` when the `Textblock` is present is because the `Textbox` is visually on top of the `NavigationView`. So when you click anywhere on the app, the `click` is registered on to the `Textblock` and not the `NavigationView`.

Consider it like this, the `Textbock` has a transparent background hence you can't see it being visually covering the whole app area but in your `visual studio designer` you can see that when you click on the `Textblock` the selection goes to the whole app area instead of the small section on the text.

### Solution:

Well it's quite simple, give your `Textbox` a `Height` or `Width` or some kind of an `Alignment` (horizontal or vertical), like below:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="AppTitle" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Test"/>
```

> Please note: I would highly recommend you use `Grid.RowDefinitions` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` of the parent `grid` and `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` with `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` of your `Textblock` to align your textbox to keep it more adaptive. Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38848600/3766231) to have a deeper understanding on keeping your UI adaptive

I hope this helps, please do let me know in case of any queries